# How to record when user navigates away from iframe site

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a site which sits within an iframe.

**How can I detect and record the time that a user navigates away from my site?**

I started doing this:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  $.post('record_action.php');
});
```

but what was happpening was that the ajax function fired, but did not complete because the page navigated away and the ajax function ended early (did not connect properly)

Comment: `but what was happpening was that the ajax function fired, but did not complete because the page navigated away` I'm glad it didn't wait for your AJAX! call to complete. I would hate it to wait for some call back to the server before I could navigate away :) This doesn't answer your question though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because AJAX calls are **asynchronous by default**, before your `$.post` is called, the page is closed and no result is sent to your server.

You need to use synchronous ajax call here to make sure the page closes **after** the post submission.

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "record_action.php",
      async: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(){
        //
      }
    });
});
```